# Using a function as a callback or storing it?

Tags: javascript, function

I can do this

```
var element; // some html node

element.addEventListener("click", function() {
     alert(1);
}, false);
```

Or this;

```
var clickFunc = function() {
    alert(1);
}

element.addEventListener("click", clickFunc, false);
```

Does it matter which one I do? I have read all over the internet that the two approaches differ and I am struggling to see why?

Comment: I don't think there is any difference in this case.

Comment: One obvious advantages is that you can call `removeEventListener` with the function reference.

Comment: The second one could be helpful if you have a clickfunction you want to apply to different elements. You can reuse the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a third alternative:

```
function clickFunc() {
  alert(1);
}

element.addEventListener("click", clickFunc, false);
```

The advantage here is that the name ("clickFunc") will show up in stack traces if there are exceptions thrown.

You can also do this if you really like typing:

```
var clickFunc = function clickFunc() {
  alert(1);
};
```

Or, shorter:

```
element.addEventListener("click", function clickFunc() {
  alert(1);
}, false);
```

but those have [some minor issues](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/) in older browsers.

Comment: I didn't think of the third alternative, I think I will stick with your first example, it is clearly the best option, thank you this has helped me alot.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing as far as performance or functionality is concerned, but if you are going for any re-usability then the second option is better.

```
var clickFunc = function() {
    alert(1);
}

element.addEventListener("click", clickFunc, false);
element1.addEventListener("click", clickFunc, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are doing the same thing. It's just with anonymous function you will not be able to call removeListener.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer second option. It's more reusable and testable also you can use `removeEventListener`. There isn't any difference in terms of performance and functionality.